# Django form select widget's label

Tags: django, django-forms

now, whenever I create a model form which has a FK field, a select menu shows up and the first item is --------- which means that nothing is selected. How can I change -------- to "Choose something" or whatever I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the emtpy label of ModelChoiceField. You can set it by `ModelChoiceField(empty_label=u'your text here')`.